# Jquery validationengine in asp.net Updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Asp.net webforms site that I'm using jquery validation engine ([source](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)) to validate my controls. I'm also using bootstrap to style my controls.

It's working fine, however my bootstrap select boxes have given me some trouble.  When placed in an updatepanel, the bootstrap select box would lose it's style during partial postbacks.  So I had to rebind the select style by adding this script:

```
function pageLoad() {
            $('.select').unbind();
            $('.select').selectpicker();
        }
```

This maintains the style and is working great.  But now I've noticed that the jquery validationengine is no longer working when placed in an updatepanel. Is the partial postback stripping that out too? The odd thing is that I have other updatepanels on the same page, and if one of the other fields isn't valid first, and then I select the bootstrap select box, it maintains it's validationstyle.  I guess because the first error in the other panel is restricting this control from posting back and losing the style?

Here is my code.  The bottom updatepanel is the one that contains the select box in question.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 control-label">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-7"> 
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtFirstNameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" 
                                                    Text="This field is required"
                                                    Display="None"
                                                    CssClass="label label-danger label-form"
                                                    ValidationGroup="MainValidationGroup" />

                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtFirstNameRegExp" runat="server"    
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                                                    Text="Maximum 50 characters"
                                                    ValidationExpression="^.{0,50}$"
                                                    Display="None"
                                                    CssClass="label label-danger label-form"   
                                                    ValidationGroup="MainValidationGroup" />

                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></span>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control validate[required,maxSize[50]]" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged"/>

                                                </div>                                  
                                            </div>
                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="txtFirstName" EventName ="TextChanged" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 control-label">Status</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-7">

                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ddlStatusRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="ddlStatus" 
                                                    Text="This field is required"
                                                    Display="None"
                                                    CssClass="label label-danger label-form"
                                                    ValidationGroup="MainValidationGroup" />

                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" CSSClass="form-control select show-tick validate[required]" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" OnChange="$(this).validationEngine('validate');"/>

                                            </div>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="ddlStatus" EventName ="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What do I need to change, or add to make sure the jquery validationengine stays active on the bootstrap select after updatepanel postback, in the same way it does my textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the validator is typically instantiated with a call in the following format, the plugin can only be instanciated on form elements:

```
$("#form1").validationEngine();
```

I hope you are validating your form on button click and that button stay inside the update panel.

I had test your code in my machine and working great with combination of bootstrap as well as validation-engine.

Add below script before completion of body tag `</body>`. Please remember "UpdatePanel1" is the id of your update-panel where your submit button reside.

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ucb.org.br/Scripts/formValidator/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ucb.org.br/Scripts/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_initializeRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate.join().indexOf("UpdatePanel1") != -1) {
                if (!$("[id*=UpdatePanel1]").validationEngine('validate')) {
                    e.set_cancel(true);
                }
            }
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate.join().indexOf("UpdatePanel2") != -1) {
                if (!$("[id*=UpdatePanel2]").validationEngine('validate')) {
                    e.set_cancel(true);
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Here you find the demo and source code of [validating controls using jQuery validation-engine with update panel](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-ValidationEngine-Plugin-with-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel.aspx).

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this logic, however I'm still running into the same issue.  This maintains my bootstrap select style, however the jquery validation (which is added by the select's "validate[required]" class) still isn't working.  It only works when the first name text box is invalid first in the other updatepanel

Comment: Also, if the other updatepanel is valid and posts back, the select box in the other panel loses the validation style

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have provide you some description and demo to resolve your problem. Please check and let me know.